# Accepted/Unaccepted filter for Answers/Questions in our Profile Menu

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer

For Questions and Answers in our Profile Menu we have the option to filter them on the basis of Score/Activity/Newest/Views but more than often feel the need for a Accepted/Unaccepted filter for both Q n A.

Can we have such a feature?

Comment: As a work-around, you can put `hasaccepted:1` in the search box to look for only accepted answers (or not accepted if you use `hasaccepted:0`). And include `user:me` to restrict the search to your own posts.

Comment: @PeterPhipps it works, great. :)

Comment: @PeterPhipps though `hasaccepted:0`+`hasaccepted:1` $\ne$ MyTotalAnswers but `isaccepted:no`+`isaccepted:yes` $=$ MyTotalAnswers. (Got idea from suggestions of search bar itself.)

Comment: Yes, `hasaccepted` is for questions and `isaccepted` is for answers. My earlier comment was wrong.

Comment: More filters in the searching help: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/searching

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut wow, they always had that?! For the first time I got to know why SE is still sticking with their search bar (lol). Though it would be better for SE to provide that info as small "i" symbol besides their search bar over which when mouse hovers, it shows some valuable info and also the link that you provided. This might be a separate meta-SE post though (not by me).